# Array.find() provides strange results

Tags: c#, arrays

I am in middle of writing an assignment for my part time programming course. The issues with my code is the array.find() and results of that search. It should(In my theory) search the array for information and then post them to the user, however what comes out from all of the searches is the same thing:   ass2task1.Program+customer                Here are only parts of the code becouse out teacher told us we can post question on the internet as long as we don't post our entire codes

```
 struct customer
    {
        public int customernumber;
        public string customersurname;
        public string customerforname;
        public string customerstreet;
        public string customertown;
        public DateTime customerdob;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        customer[] customerdetails = new customer[99];
        int selector = 0;
        int selector2 = 0;
        string vtemp = "";
        string ctemp = "";
        int searchnumber;
        string searchforename;    //variable/ array declaring
        string searchsurname;
        string searchtown;
        DateTime searchdob;
        customer resultnumber;
        customer resultforename;
        customer resultsurname;
        customer resulttown;
        customer resultdob;


  if (selector2 == 2)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter the forename you are looking for: ");
                        searchforename = (Console.ReadLine());
                        resultforename = Array.Find(customerdetails, customer => customer.customerforname == searchforename);
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter the surname you are looking for: "); // all of the searches comes out with ass2task1.Program+customer  result
                        searchsurname = (Console.ReadLine());
                        resultsurname = Array.Find(customerdetails, customer => customer.customersurname == searchsurname);
                        Console.WriteLine("The forename resuts:" + resultforename);
                        Console.WriteLine("The surname resuts:" + resultsurname);
```

Comment: Are you actually populating the customer details array with any customers? The code only shows you declaring an array which will hold 99 items

Comment: In your comment line "ass2task1.Program+customer" what is ass2task1?  Additionally you're setting selecttor2 to 0, and then have an if block that only gets hit when that selector2 var is 2, can you provide more relevant code to what your problems actually is?  Additionally are you populating your array with data?

Comment: @Kritner `ass2task1` is probably the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.Find()` will return the object that matches a predicate, if you want the property value, you would need to do something like: `resultforename.customerforname` or something similar.

If it is not found, then a default value will be returned, so check for nulls etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you convert an object to a string (`"The forename resuts:" + resultforename`) it calls the objects `ToString()` method. Define an appropriate `ToString()` method:

```
struct customer
{
    public int customernumber;
    public string customersurname;
    public string customerforname;
    public string customerstreet;
    public string customertown;
    public DateTime customerdob;

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return customersurname + ", " + customerforname;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To (attempt to) expand on Ric and clcto's answers.  The reason you're getting the struct name in your

```
Console.WriteLine("The forename resuts:" + resultforename);
Console.WriteLine("The surname resuts:" + resultsurname);
```

Your resultforename is of struct customer - by default Console.WriteLine(struct) does not know how to represent a complex object as a string.

As suggested you could do

```
Console.WriteLine("The forename resuts:" + resultforename.customerforname);
```

Or provide your own .ToString() method for the struct as clcto pointed out - doing this you're basically telling Console.WriteLine (or any string representation) *how* to represent a struct of customer as string.

Don't know if this will help, or make it even less clear.  But given:

```
public struct Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public struct FooTwo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "This is how to represent a Foo2 as string: " + Bar;
    }
}

Foo[] foos = new Foo[99];

Foo foundFoo = foos[0]; // This is equivalent to your find statement... setting a foundFoo local variable to a Foo struct
string foundBar = foos[0].Bar; // This is another way to get to what you're trying to accoomplish, setting a string value representation of your found object.

Console.WriteLine(foundFoo); // Doesn't know how to deal with printing out a Foo struct - simply writes [namespace].Foo
Console.WriteLine(foundFoo.Bar); // Outputs Foo.Bar value
Console.WriteLine(foundBar); // Outputs Foo.Bar value

FooTwo foo2 = new FooTwo();
foo2.Bar = "test bar";

Console.WriteLine(foo2); // outputs: "This is how to represent a Foo2 as string: test bar"
```